# Jquery hide/ show svg images

Tags: c#, jquery, css, svg, show-hide

[enter image description here][1]Help!
I have two svg image buttons on my page. On the page load I am displaying one of the two buttons based on the value in the DB . and I have jquery to hide that button and show another one on button click from UI. I cannot show another button after hide.

both buttons are in a single span class.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and add it to the question.

Comment: I did Robert. Help is much appreciated

Comment: That's neither minimal, nor complete and therefore not verifiable either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. My back end code was using property btnXX.Visible = false, Changing it to display:none fixed my issue.

If you don't want to render the control at all in certain situations, set Visible="false". Since it keeps the control's HTML out of the page, slightly but if you want to show the control via Ajax/etc, this won't work and display:none css should be used

Answer (score 1):

The `visibility` property can't be `block`. You should use `visible` instead.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) for more about this property.

---

**EDIT**
If that can help... Here is an example showing both `hidden` and `visible` for the `visibility` attribute...

```js
// That is executed on load.
$("#btnXX").css("visibility", "visible"); 
$("#btnYY").css("visibility", "hidden");

// Handler for the toggle button.
$("#toggle").on("click", function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  if($(this).hasClass("active")){
    $("#btnXX").css("visibility", "hidden"); 
    $("#btnYY").css("visibility", "visible");
  }else{
    $("#btnXX").css("visibility", "visible"); 
    $("#btnYY").css("visibility", "hidden");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btnXX">XX</button><button id="btnYY">YY</button><br>
<br>
<button id="toggle">Toggle it</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Louys, But visible property also gives me same issue..

Comment: I added an example... Hoping that will help.

Comment: Appreciate you taking time to write this Louys, But in my situation, I have two buttons. btnXX and btnYY.  I do not have/need a toggle button. Upon page load, one of the buttons is shown based on a DB flag ( works fine) lets say btnXX is shown. From UI when i click btnXX it updates the flag in DB to show btnYY, btnXX should hide and btnYY should be shown. All works fine ( updating the DB , Hiding if the btnXX)  only thing that does not work is showing up of btnYY.  no buttons are shows up on UI, untill I refresh the page. Refreshing pulls up the right button. Thanks again!

Comment: Is btnYY hidden using `visibility` or another property? If you used `display:none` you have to use `display:block` to show it back. Or maybe you used `opacity:0` !?! Then set it back to `opacity:1`. Check if you use the right `id` too... The only other possibility I see is that btnYY element is not even present in DOM. Check all this... I can't tell more since you did not post the code making that button hidden on load.

Comment: Thanks Louys! I have edited my post with my code..  Also if it helps when I do f12, I do not see the other button.